# delete mysql table row in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have mysql table

parent table with  cat_id, name and post_id

child table with  name and cat_id

parent.cat_id = child.cat_id

for example parent table have two rows post_id = 3 and with different cat_id

and with parent cat_id = child cat_id.

i try delete post id = 3 and all the child row which match parent.cat_id

```
DELETE FROM parent t1, child t2 USING t1, t2 WHERE t1.cat_id = t2.cat_id and t1.post_id = 3
```

above code i try can't make it woking, can anyone give me some help or suggestion, thanks

just figure it out

```
DELETE c.*, b.* FROM wp_menu_category c LEFT JOIN wp_menu_food b ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id WHERE c.post_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-delete-query.htm) for deleting rows.

You do not need "USING t1, t2"

```
DELETE * FROM parent t1, child t2 WHERE t1.cat_id = t2.cat_id and t1.post_id = 3
```

Comment: thanks i just figure it out `DELETE c.*, b.* FROM wp_menu_category c LEFT JOIN wp_menu_food b ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id WHERE c.post_id = 3`